# devise destroy session path is conflicting with another user path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have have devise set up for my User model.

However, when I try to call the destroy session path:

link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path

But when I click on the link it sends me to

> .../users/sign_out

I get the following error, because sign_out is not valid user obviously:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

How do I get around this? I have tried this but it doesn't even seem to recognize it's n the routes.

```
devise_scope :users do
  delete "user/signout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_session
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes file, you've specified that this route should be matched on a `DELETE` request. However, your signout link is sending a `GET` request. This is why the request is matching `UserControllers#show`.

Assuming you're using `jquery`, you can set up this link to send the signout request as `DELETE` by making sure you've added `jquery_ujs` to the included javascript. This will modify the request method for links that have the `data-method` attribute set to something other than 'GET', To specify the proper `:method` param for your signout `link_to`, use:

```
link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

Of course, this will only work if your users have Javascript enabled; otherwise, the request will fallback to `GET` anyways. If you want to make signout work for `GET` requests, it will need to have higher precedence in your routes file than the show route.